# VPN Shortcut Doesn't Appear on Notification Center Since build 10586

Tags: insider-preview, action-center

I use Lumia 640 XL with Windows 10 build 10586.36 , but I found I'm missing VPN Shortcuts from notification action center. is there any setting to make it available on my action center

[image]

Comment: If you go to Settings > System > Notifications & Actions and try to change your Quick Actions, does it show up in the list of options?

Comment: unfortunately nope, is it gone by the update , or is it still there in the last build?

Comment: I'm actually on a 950XL on the release build, so I'm not sure about that.